# How can I get tag's text value with xsl transformation

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a XML like this

```
<Error>An error has occured while saving the workflow
    <ErrorFile>C:\temp\Log\ErrorImages\accountwf38_1401351602333.png</ErrorFile>
</Error>
```

when I write an XSL transformation like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="Error"/>
```

I am getting the entire error value as output, including the error file value.
But I need only `An error has occured while saving the workflow` as output. How can I write a transformation for that?

Thanks

Rajendar

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="Error/text()"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *i am getting entire error value as output including error file value but i need only An error has occurred while saving the workflow as output*

The `<Error>` element has *three* child nodes. A text node, an element (`ErrorFile`) node and another text node (containing a new line and some spaces before the end tag)`.

The XPath expression you used selects the entire `Error` node, which is converted to its [string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) when used in `<xsl:value-of>`, which consists of of all of its descendants converted to string.

To obtain what you need you can use this expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Error/text()"/>
```

which will select only the child *text* nodes.

And you can get rid of the unnecessary spaces using:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Error/text())"/>
```